# Crop an Image, by specifing four corner points (non-rectangular)

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

Need to create a function, which crops an image, given four points.

Input:---------->Image, four corner points

Output:------->Cropped image

I have come across two types of cropping functions so far,

1)which uses a point, Height & width

2)which uses a point, height, width & an angle
However these functions don't seem to solve my issue completely.

In order to be more clear, I have tried to depict my intentions in the image below.
[Cropping an image, by specifying corner points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x21me.png)

Comment: Please show code you've tried and have problem with...

Comment: public static Bitmap CropRotatedRect(Bitmap source, Rectangle rect, float angle, bool HighQuality)
{
   Bitmap result = new Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height);
   using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(result))
   {
       g.InterpolationMode = HighQuality ? InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic : InterpolationMode.Default;
        using (Matrix mat = new Matrix())
        {
           mat.Translate(-rect.Location.X, -rect.Location.Y);
           mat.RotateAt(angle, rect.Location);
           g.Transform = mat;
           g.DrawImage(source, new Point(0, 0));
        }
    }
    return result;
}

Comment: I have used the above code, however when the input region is a trapezium, the function doesn't seem to work.
If there was a function, which would take 4 points as input, & then process it, it would be a solution to all the input region types.
At least, that's what I feel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found the solution to my problem :)

```
// define quadrilateral's corners
List<IntPoint> corners = new List<IntPoint>( );
corners.Add( new IntPoint(  x1,  y1 ) );
corners.Add( new IntPoint( x2,  y2 ) );
corners.Add( new IntPoint( x3, y3 ) );
corners.Add( new IntPoint( x4, y4 ) );
// create filter
QuadrilateralTransformation filter=new QuadrilateralTransformationBilinear( corners, NewWidth, NewHeight );
// apply the filter
Bitmap newImage = filter.Apply( image );
```

This would convert any quadrilateral into a Rectangular one.
It helped me, hope this information is helpful to others as well.